# Is there a issue in having a function with no arguments () within a grails controller?

Tags: grails

I am facing a weird issue with an grails (1.3.7) application hosted in tomcat.

While the application is in use continuously the application freezes at some point in time (hang state). While tracing the issue, I find that just at the time of freeze one of the function with zero argument (eg. getLinceneInfo() which is part of the controller code) is randomly getting called and never returns. There were three such functions within the controller code and each time I changed these functions to be called with atleast one dummy argument, this issue manifested on the function that that did not have any argument (). Once all the 3 functions were changed to pass an argument, this issue did not recur.

Can somebody throw some light on this random behavior?

Regards,
Reno

Answer (score 0):

Before 2.0 all controller actions were closures. They're still supported, but methods are preferred now. To discover closures that should be considered actions, your controller class is instantiated and the getters are called to determine their return type. This is because whenever you have a property in a Groovy class that looks like

```
def foo = ...
```

what happens is that the Groovy compiler turns that into a private field, and adds a getter and setter, in this case `Object getFoo() { ... }` and `void setFoo(Object foo) { ... }`. If you have one or both of these methods already they won't be overwritten though. This is how properties work in domain classes, taglibs, and controllers. Since the closure is defined with `def` there's no way to know if it's a Closure, or a String, or whatever, so calling the getter is needed.

The simplest workaround here is to change the method name to not look like a getter. One common pattern that still looks like a getter is to change it to `licenceInfo()`.